# Audio from AVAudioPlayer doesn't make a sound

Tags: ios, swiftui

Here is the code that **does not work** (sound successfully plays but doesn't make a sound):

```
struct MultipleChoiceOption: View {
    let soundManager = SoundManager()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            SoundManager().playSound(name: "click.wav")
```

Whereas this code **does work**:

```
struct MultipleChoiceOption: View {
    let soundManager = SoundManager()

    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            self.soundManager.playSound(name: "click.wav")
```

**Viewmodel**

```
class SoundManager: ObservableObject {
    var player: AVAudioPlayer?
    
    func playSound(name: String){
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: nil)
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path!)
        print("Play URL from name: \(name)")
        do {
            player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
            player?.play()
            print("Played sound")
        } catch {
            print("Error playing \(name) sound")
        }
    }
}
```

I don't get it. Why does the second code block work but the first doesn't?

Comment: What is the output of print statements in both the cases?

Comment: Both the same.  1st print: Play URL from name: click.wav  2nd print: Played sound @SHS

Comment: As per my knowledge, in second case, the self.soundmanager object is alive, outside of action clouser. So it can play the AVAudioPlayer method (which is async). But in first case, SoundManager() object completes it's lifecycle, when action clouser ends. So .play() does not (async) make sound in first case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think a bit about what the two approaches actually do.
In the second case, you create a SoundManager object and assign it to a variable that is part of your MultipleChoiceOption object. Therefore, it will live as long as the MultipleChoiceOption object is alive. Then you use that SoundManager to play the sound.

In the first case, you create an ***other*** SoundManager object when the button is pressed, but never assign it to a variable. That is, it will live until the end of the action method and then be terminated immediately, long before it manages to play sound.